# Entity Framework DBSet Extensions for type that implements an interface

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

I am trying to create some `DbSet<T>` extensions where `T` implements `INWatchStandardEntity`.

Here is any example of one of them:

```
public static class NWatchDbSetExtensions
{
    public static Int32 GenerateId<TEntity>(this DbSet<INWatchStandardEntity> dbSet, string name) 
        where TEntity : INWatchStandardEntity, new()
    {
        NWatchObjectType objectType = Common.ToObjectType(dbSet.GetType());
        return Common.GetObjectIdFromName(objectType, name);
    }
}
```

This compiles fine, however, when I try to use the `GenerateId(string name)` on a `DbSet` that inherits from `INWatchStandardEntity`, for example:

```
using (var context = Application.GetDbContext()) {
    context.Nodes.GenerateId<INWatchStandardEntity>("name"); 
}
```

I get the following message:

> '`DbSet<Node>`' does not contain a definition for 'GenerateId' and the
>   best extension method overload
>   'NWatchDbSetExtensions.GenerateId(`DbSet<INWatchStandardEntity>`,
>   `string`)' requires a receiver of type '`DbSet<INWatchStandardEntity>`'

Is there a way to make this and other extension methods available so that I can use it against any DbSet where Entity implements INWatchStandardEntity?

Comment: change `this DbSet<INWatchStandardEntity> dbSet` to `this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet`

Comment: When I do that, I get the message that 'The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbSet<TEntity>' '.

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation, here is the correct way of doing this:

```
public static Int32 GenerateId<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, string name) 
    where TEntity : class, INWatchStandardEntity
{
    NWatchObjectType objectType = Common.ToObjectType(dbSet.GetType());
    return Common.GetObjectIdFromName(objectType, name);
}
```